# C# Web.Security Enable ressources before Authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, webmethod

I'm performing a site using the ASP.net Authentication (I'm following the tutorial below : 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

I'm trying to implement the logon_click method in the code behinf file (Logon.aspx.cs), so all the authentication code (username and password) couldnt be on the client side.

In order to consume the WebMethod logon_click(Authentication method), I use the AJAX and Javascript methods. My problem is that until the user is authenticated, all ressources (like WebMethod) are unabled to use... Of course, my goal is to call this WebMethod in order to Authenticate the user..., but if all ressources are disabled...I cant do it !

Do you have some idea how to enable only some ressources whitout an Authentication ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, It was just very simple.... :D !

If you're using code-behind, make sure you change "private" to "protected" since the .aspx page inherits from the .aspx.cs file's class.

That's all :D !